# Angular Typescript UWP Cannot Use C# WinRT component classes

Tags: angular, typescript, uwp, windows-runtime

I have A UWP application being developed in Angular5. I want that application to use Windows Runtime Component(Universal) classes to access data from table.
like this

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';


  ngOnInit() {
    var test = new AngularUWP.RuntimeComponent.TestClass();
    let world = test.testFunction();
  }

}
```

now, when I Build, i get error that  'TS2304:Cannot find name 'AngularUWP'
How to solve this.
Github sample project [here](https://github.com/JinsPeter/AngularUWP)

OR

**I just want my angular compiler to skip these class names intact when it is found**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up declaring the name AngularUWP as a constant.

```
declare const AngularUWP:any;
```

Comment: That is not a type declaration

Comment: @AluanHaddad What do u mean. It is a known constant type for the application. Only that typescript/Angular app does not know about it.

Comment: you're declaring a value not a type